# Passport Local Strategy not saving user in cookie or session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, passport.js

I'm attempting to use passport with express 4 and authenticate with a local strategy. I'm trying to get a simple setup working but I'm have issues.

I'm try to authenticate with an authorization middleware function... deserializeUser is never called, req.user is undefined and the user data is missing from both the sessions and cookies.

My server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path')

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var dust = require('express-dustjs')

var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var authService = require('./app/services/auth.js')
var dbConfig = require('./app/config.js')['documentDB'];
var authService = require('./app/services/auth.js');

/*
 * DUST JS
 */

// Dustjs settings 
dust._.optimizers.format = function (ctx, node) {
  return node
}

// Define custom Dustjs helper 
dust._.helpers.demo = function (chk, ctx, bodies, params) {
  return chk.w('demo')
}

// Use Dustjs as Express view engine 
app.engine('dust', dust.engine({
  // Use dustjs-helpers 
  useHelpers: true
}))

/*
 * STATIC ASSETS
*/
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'dust')
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, './app/views'))

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser('X+a1+TKXwd26mkiUUwqzqQ=='));
app.use(session({ 
  secret: 'X+a1+TKXwd26mkiUUwqzqQ==',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie : { secure : true, maxAge : (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000) }
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, X-AUTHENTICATION, X-IP, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

// Configure Passport authenticated session persistence.
//
// In order to restore authentication state across HTTP requests, Passport needs
// to serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  The
// typical implementation of this is as simple as supplying the user ID when
// serializing, and querying the user record by ID from the database when
// deserializing.
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  console.log('serializeUser : ', user);
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  console.log('-------------------------------');
  console.log('-------------------------------');
  console.log('deserializeUser : ', id);
  console.log('-------------------------------');
  console.log('-------------------------------');
  authService.getAccountByID(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    cb(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
  }, function(username, password, callback) {

    authService.authenticate(username, password, function(err, user) {

      if (err) {
        console.log("ERR >> ", err);
        return callback(err, false, err);
      }    

      return callback(err, user);

    }); 
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride());
/*
 * ROUTES
*/

app.use('/', require('./app/routes/index.js')(passport));
app.use('/prototypes/', require('./app/routes/prototypes.js'));
app.use('/auth', require('./app/routes/auth')(passport));

/*
 * APP START
 */

app.listen(port, function () {
  var msg = 'Express started > ';

  console.log('Express started >> ');
  console.log('  env: ', process.env.NODE_ENV);

}).on('error', function(err){
    console.log('ON ERROR >> ');
    console.log(err);
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log('ON UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION >>');
    console.log(err);
});
```

The middleware function and route.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var controller = require('../controllers/index.js');

module.exports = function(passport) {

  router.get('/', controller.index);

  router.get('/test', verifyAuth, function(req, res) {
    return res.status(200)
      .json({"req.isAuth" : req.isAuth});
  });

  return router;

};

function verifyAuth(req,res,next) {

  console.log('req.cookies : ', req.cookies);

  console.log('req.login', req.login);
  console.log('req.isAuthenticated : ', req.isAuthenticated);
  console.log('req.session', req.session);
  console.log('req.user : ', req.user);

  if ( !req.isAuthenticated() ) { 
     res.status( 400 );      // constant defined elsewhere, accessible here
     return res.end('Please Login'); // or a redirect in a traditional web app, 
  }                                   // as opposed to an SPA
  next();
}
```

Here is the login route:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('local',  function(err, user, info) {
      if (err || !user) {
        return res.send(500, info);
      }

      req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
          console.log('ERROR > ', error);
        }

        return res.json(200, user);
      });
    })(req, res, next);

});
```

Comment: can you move your headers after you have initialised `passport.seesion` ? sometime it happens due to cross origin.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg Thanks for your response, but still no luck... :0(

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to put the passport logic in `app.post();` not only in `app.use()`:

```
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Check out this example server.js form the passport team on github:
[Passport Example](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to post that part. I added the login route I am using. That action is using a custom authentication function, I think that's where the problem is...